# Automatically filling in user into form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am attempting to automatically assign a user to a questionnaire that they fill out.

Here is part of my views.py file:

```
@login_required
def questionnaireAnswerView(request):
    form = QuestionnaireForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/accounts/profile/")

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "questionnaire/createNewQuestionnaire.html", context)
```

This is my createNewQuestionnaire.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Questionnaire" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my form.py

```
class QuestionnaireForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questionnaire
        fields = [
            'name',
            'organisationType',
            'organisationIncome',
            'programArea',
            'appliedForFunding',
            'successfullyFundedBefore',
            'sourcesOfIncome',
            'planToGenerateIncome',
            'skillsToReachTargets',
            'processesToRecruit',
            'processesToUpskill',
            'confidentSpeakingAboutProject',
            'knowGoodCharity',
            'collectPastSuccessFunding',
            'collectPastFailedFunding',
            'areasOfAdditionalHelp'
        ]
```

And finally, this is *part* of my model.py. I have not shown the types of choices here.

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=False, null=False)
    organisationType = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=typeOfCharity, blank=False, null=False)
    organisationIncome = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=incomeLevels, blank=False, null=False)
    
    ...
```

I think I need to make changes to my veiws.py file. In particular, I believe I need to somehow access the form that is returned from the request.POST and then set the currently logged in user as the user required.

I have tried passing in the user through to the form itself and filling in the user field but this allows the interacting user to change who the questionnaire is assigned to.

Comment: Why is the `user` field `unique=True`? A *user* can only make *one* `Questionaire`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That is correct. One user can only make one questionnaire.

Comment: then it is advisable to work with a `OneToOneField`, since that is in essence a `ForeignKey` that is unique: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `.user` attribute of the `.instance` wrapped in the form:

```
@login_required
def questionnaireAnswerView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionnaireForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/')
    else:
        form = QuestionnaireForm(request.POST)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'questionnaire/createNewQuestionnaire.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Usually it is better to work with a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)
> instead of a `ForeignKey` that has `unique=True`. A `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` and some small
> modifications: for example it uses by default the name of the model in lowercase as
> [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> and makes accessing the relation in reverse more convenient since that does not require a *manager* in between.

Comment: Hi, thank you this seems to work. However, I am still concerned about the 'notes' you've referenced. For the first note, are you advising that I use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of just User in my model definition? And on the second note, how do I make an OneToOneField that stores my users?

Comment: @SyedArafatQureshi: `user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE), and you `from django.conf import settings`.